# win32 scrollbar in not working in C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, .net, winapi

[win32 scrollbar in not working screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge7yT.png)

Win32 scrollbar in not working. This is my code in win32 C/C++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND text, text2, button, mm;
HMENU hmenu;
void AddMenus(HWND);
char textsave[20];



/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] ="CodeBlocksWindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       "",       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       544,                 /* The programs width */
       375,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}



/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
    case WM_CREATE:

        CreateWindow("EDIT", "jdslfkjssf\r\n\r\n\r\nflkjsdf\r\nflskdjfkl",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                            20, 70, 490, 130, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

         CreateWindow("EDIT", "jdslfkjssf\r\n\r\n\r\nflkjsdf\r\nflskdjfkl",
                            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                            20, 270, 490, 230, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);



        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:

        break;


    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}



return 0;
}
```

The scrollbar is not working here. I want the scrollbar to be pulled down so that the rest of the bottom can be seen. How to write this code, will the scrollbar work?

Comment: You are forgot implement WM_VSCROLL message

Comment: I'm new in win32 api. I can't write the code correctly. It would be helpful for me to write the full code correctly.

Comment: @user2120666 Please help me by entering the correct code.

Comment: @farukfaruk Does my solution work for you?

Comment: @Rita Han Yes. It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to Scroll vertically**

**1. Get scrolling unit.**

Scrolling units are typically set while processing the `WM_CREATE` message. For example, in your case, you display text in edit control, so here we can take the height of a character cell, plus external leading as one vertical scrolling unit. To retrieve the font dimensions for a specific DC, use the `GetTextMetrics` function.

**2. Processing the `WM_SIZE` Message**

When processing the `WM_SIZE` message, it is convenient to adjust the scrolling range and scrolling position to reflect the dimensions of the client area.

The `SetScrollInfo` function sets the minimum and maximum position values, the page size, and the scrolling position for a scroll bar.

**3. Processing the `WM_VSCROLL` Messages.**

When user click the top arrow, the bottom arrow, the scroll bar shaft above the scroll box, the scroll bar shaft below the scroll box and dragged the scroll box, the scroll bar sends `WM_VSCROLL` messages to the window procedure.

When the `WM_VSCROLL` message is processed, the scroll bar request code is examined and the scrolling increment is calculated. After the increment is applied to the current scrolling position, the window is scrolled to the new position by using the `ScrollWindowEx` function, and the position of the scroll box is adjusted by using the `SetScrollInfo` function.

After a window is scrolled, part of its client area is made invalid. To ensure that the invalid region is updated, the `UpdateWindow` function is used to generate a `WM_PAINT` message.

The following is an example of scroll the whole client area of main window you can refer to.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    SCROLLINFO si;

    // These variables are required to display text. 
    static int xClient;     // width of client area 
    static int yClient;     // height of client area 
    static int yChar; // vertical scrolling unit
    static int yPos;  // current vertical scrolling position

    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        editCtl1 = CreateWindow("EDIT", "jdslfkjssf\r\n\r\n\r\nflkjsdf\r\nflskdjfkl",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
            20, 70, 490, 130, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        editCtl2 = CreateWindow("EDIT", "jdslfkjssf\r\n\r\n\r\nflkjsdf\r\nflskdjfkl",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
            20, 270, 490, 230, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        // Get the handle to the client area's device context. 
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        // Extract font dimensions from the text metrics. 
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        yChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

        // Free the device context. 
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        break;
    }

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        // Retrieve the dimensions of the client area. 
        yClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        xClient = LOWORD(lParam);

        // Get y-coordinate (bottom) of the second edit control 
        RECT editCtl2Rect = { 0 };
        GetWindowRect(editCtl2, &editCtl2Rect);
        POINT point = { 0 };
        point.x = editCtl2Rect.right;
        point.y = editCtl2Rect.bottom;

        // Convert screen coordinate to parent client-area coordinates
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &point);

        // Set the vertical scrolling range and page size
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = point.y / yChar;
        si.nPage = yClient / yChar;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        break;
    }

    case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
        // Get all the vertial scroll bar information.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // Save the position for comparison later on.
        yPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            // User clicked the top arrow.
        case SB_LINEUP:
            si.nPos -= 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the bottom arrow.
        case SB_LINEDOWN:
            si.nPos += 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft above the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEUP:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft below the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEDOWN:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // User dragged the scroll box.
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Set the position and then retrieve it.  Due to adjustments
        // by Windows it may not be the same as the value set.
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // If the position has changed, scroll window and update it.
        if (si.nPos != yPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, yChar * (yPos - si.nPos), NULL, NULL);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);       
        break;
    default:                      
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Refer to "[Using Scroll Bars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/using-scroll-bars)" for more detailed information.